# Disable Speech Recognition API notification on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, speech-recognition, annyang

If you go to a page that uses the web SpeechRecognition API, like the [demo page for Annyang.js](https://www.talater.com/annyang/), on the Android Chrome browser, you'll notice that once the mic starts listening for speech input, it will make a notification sound just like the Google Now speech input. And since the speech recognition is activated multiple times to make it seem like it is continuously listening, it gets very annoying.

I'd like to have a kiosk tablet that has a page using Annyang.js, or some other SpeechRecognition API library, to always be listening for commands. However, this notification sound would make it infeasible to leave the volume turned up, and I'd like to be able to play some audio.

**Is there a way to disable the audible notification when activating the Speech Recognition API in Android Chrome?**

This doesn't have to be on the webpage. I can modify the Android device as needed.

Comment: You cannot do this in a web page. This is a security feature and cannot be disabled for privacy reasons. If you need to do this you should consider something like a cordova app, for which you can then make an extension to control this behaviour.

Comment: @Ben I figured that was the case, but that doesn't really help me unless you explain how a Cordova extension would solve this? I was more looking for a browser or Android setting/modification to do this.